# Datastore entity with kind and key has a null property named

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After adding a boolean attribute to an object, fetching that object from the datastore results in the error:

```
Datastore entity with kind <Class> and key <Class:ID> has a 
  null property named <attribute>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use primitive data-types, use their wrapper classes.
Instead of boolean, use Boolean, etc.